# How to join column in pandas ignoring the value of Zero with mixed datatypes

Tags: python, pandas

My data looks like this: (I have 28 columns)

```
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5
AA    0    0    B    0
0    CC    0    D    0
0    0    E    F    G
```

I am trying to merge these columns to get an output like this:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5    col6
AA    0    0    B    0   AA;B
0    C    0    DD    0   C;DD
0    0    E    F    G    E;F;G
```

I want to merge only the non-numeric characters into the new column.

I tried like this:

```
cols=['col1','col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5']
df2["col6"] = df2[cols].apply(lambda x: ';'.join(x.dropna()), axis=1)
```

But it doesn't take out the zeros. I am aware it is a small change but couldn't figure it out.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try via `where()` method and `apply()` method:

```
df2["col6"]=df2.where((df2!='0')&(df2!=0)).apply(lambda x: ';'.join(x.dropna()), axis=1)
```

If there are numbers other than 0(including 0) then use:

```
df2["col6"]=(df2.where(df2.apply(lambda x:x.str.isalpha(),1))
             .apply(lambda x: ';'.join(x.dropna()), axis=1))
```

Comment: Just an additional thing, what if I want to give input column numbers instead of whole data frame as my data frame consists of other columns which I don't want to include. (It's sorted)

Comment: then just select only those columns........for example `df2[['col1','col2','col3']].where((df2!='0')&(df2!=0)).apply(lambda x: ';'.join(x.dropna()), axis=1)` here we selected only 3 columns so you can change it according to your need

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples please try following. Trying to fix OP's attempts here. Simple explanation would be, major change is to use condition `x[x!=0]` to make boolean mask in OP's attempted code(join function).

```
df2['col6'] = df2[cols].apply(lambda x: ';'.join(x[x!=0]), axis=1)
```

Comment: Just a small modification with this code, as my datatype was "object" so instead of "x!=0", "x!='0'" worked. Thanks